# Is there code that can make a divs vanish/appear on click?

Tags: jquery, html

I need some code that would makes a div appear when a link is clicked.

Once this div appears, the user should be able to click the same link that they clicked to make this div appear; to make the current div vanish and a second div take its place on the screen.

Within this second div, the user should be able to close the div and be at square one, on the page with the link that opens/closes the divs when clicked.

Could any one please tell me or direct me to some code so I can implement something like I described above?

Comment: Start with http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Hi Julie. Welcome to Stackoverflow. While this is a great place to learn, you will get much more out of coding if you spend a little time working on the problem yourself and then returning to SO to ask questions about specific problems your having. Someone may still answer your question, but I encourage you to go learn a bit on your own. It will greatly increase your knowledge and help you become a better developer. Good luck!

Comment: Spend an hour browsing through the list of jQuery methods at the page zerkms linked to - the purpose of each is summarised nicely on that page, so you'll get a good idea of everything jQuery can do (for now you could skip the Ajax and Deferred methods). I think you'll find that the methods you need for your current problem become obvious, but still here's a hint: you need `.show()`, `.hide()` and `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery with following code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").on("click", function() {
      $("#id_of_the_div").toggle();
    })
  });
```

Comment: note that #link and #id_of_the_div are ids of your link and the div. You could use class selectors as well